# How to use where clause with session value in servlet

Tags: mysql, jsp, servlets, database-connection, where-clause

I have passed a value into servlet using a session.then assign the value to a variable call 'ms'. now i want to select data using that variable with 'where' clause. but it does not work.

```
    protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
        throws ServletException, IOException {

    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter(); 

         HttpSession ses=request.getSession(false);
         String ms = ses.getAttribute("ma").toString();

    try {

        dbconn = new DatabaseConnection();
        conn = dbconn.setConnection();
        stmt = conn.createStatement();
        query = "select * from  person where Email ="+ms;
        res = dbconn.getResult(query, conn);
        while(res.next()){

            lst.add(res.getString("Username"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Title"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Fname"));
            lst.add(res.getString("Lname"));

        }
        res.close();
     }catch(Exception e){

        RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("myAccount.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

    }finally{

        request.setAttribute("EmpData", lst);
        RequestDispatcher rd =request.getRequestDispatcher("myAccount.jsp");
        rd.forward(request, response);

        lst.clear();
        out.close();

    }
```

Comment: Any error it is showing?

Comment: put debug and check if`String ms = ses.getAttribute("ma").toString();` does have any value or not? if it has the value then you should use prepared statement,PreparedStatement statement=connection.prepareStatement("select * from  person where Email =?")` and associate the `?` value like this `statement.setString(1, ms);`

Answer (score 0):

It's your query causing the exception.
Instead of

```
 query = "select * from  person where Email ="+ms;
```

You should quote the email parameter.

```
query = "select * from  person where Email ='"+ms+"'";
```

But your code is vulnerable to SQL injection. It is better to use `PreparedStatement` for this.

By the way, it is also better to print the stack trace on `catch` clause, you could spot what exactly going wrong easily.